# Camel how to validate if all required file exists?

Tags: apache-camel

Not sure how to implement this in Apache Camel. My goal is only to execute the route if all files are exists. So for example we should wait until a,b,and c.txt exist, otherwise we are not executing the route.

```
String files= ["a.txt","b.txt","c.txt"];

from("file:C:\\CamelFolder\\incoming?noop=false&antInclude=*.txt")
.validate(???all 3 files must exists)
.to("file:C:\\outgoing");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` option and implement the java code in `GenericFileFilter` class and return only `true` if all those files exists: http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: That filter plugs right into the file component.  So you won't even touch the files until all 3 exist.

Comment: Correct only files where the filter method returns true is picked up by the file component

Comment: How can you check if 3 files exists in GenericFileFilter where you can only check for 1 file? How is this answer selected as correct can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this :
[OnCompletion](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html)